# Absolute error formula

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, approximation, rounding-error

Trying to figure out a problem in my textbook.
In my exercise in a textbook, a problem says that Determine the error in the approximation given that the actual length is $3.7437137$.

And in the solution in the back of the book, it says that The approximation is $3.743713701$ with an absolute error of $0.2226462$

How is $|3.743713701-3.7437137|= 0.2226462$ ? I am confused. Any help is appreciated
[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo. The actual length is $3.96635989732264...$

Comment: May I know how did you find the actual length?

Comment: Using the formula for the length we get $$\int_0^3 \sqrt{1+\frac{4 x^2}{9 (9-x^2)}} \, dx$$ Then I used Mathematica to get numerical value.